# how to have an array of radio buttons in post request of web2py

Tags: python, arrays, post, radio-button, web2py

I have some HTML like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[0]" value="1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[0]" value="2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[0]" value="3"><br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[1]" value="1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[1]" value="2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton[1]" value="3"><br>
<br>
<!-- ......... -->
```

I try to get an array in web2py like this:

```
request.post_vars.radiobutton == [1,2,2]
```

But web2py is keep giving me like this:

**request.post_vars**
**radiobutton[0]**  :   1
**radiobutton[1]**  :   2
**radiobutton[2]**  :   2

I cannot directly use them in python code. `request.post_vars.radiobutton` returns `None` and `request.post_vars.radiobutton[0]` throws TypeError: `('NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__')`

`name` property of `<input type="radio" />` cannot be `radiobutton[]` as it would make all the buttons as one.

How should I use the radio button array in web2py?

Answer (score 2):

`request.post_vars` is a `Storage` object, which is a dictionary-like object that allows access via attributes or via standard dictionary syntax. So, you can do:

```
request.post_vars['radiobutton[0]']
```

or:

```
request.post_vars.get('radiobutton[0]')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you`re trying to do is something like this:

In your Modules:

```
def radioArrayExample( name, valuesList ):
    radios = []
    for v in valuesList:
        radios.append( INPUT(_type="radio", _name=name, _value=v) )
    return radios
```

In your controller you can call that function:

```
import yourModule
def index():
    vals = [1, 2, 3]
    radios = yourModule.radioArrayExample( "exampleChoices", vals )

    return dict(radios = radios)
```

When you use "radios" inside a FORM, you'll be able to get the value you want with `request.vars.exampleChoices`
Give it a try, i guess that`s what you're looking for.